# Why is month function is not working here?

Tags: sas

A wholesale nursery is selling garden flowers, and they want to summarize their sales figures by month. Why the month function is not working?

```
    DATA sales;
    input CustID $ @9 SaleDate MMDDYY10. Petunia SnapDragon Marigold;
    datalines;
    756-01 05/04/2013 120 80 110
    834-01 05/12/2013 90 160 60
    901-02 05/18/2013 50 100 75
    834-01 06/01/2013 80 60 100
    756-01 06/11/2013 10 160 75
    901-02 06/19/2013 60 60 60
    756-01 06/25/2013 85 110 100
    ;
    Month = MONTH (SaleDate);
    run;
    PROC SORT DATA = sales;
    BY Month;
    RUN;
    PROC MEANS DATA = sales;
    VAR Petunia SnapDragon Marigold;
    by Month;
    run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid computing the extra variable `month` if you use a `CLASS` statement and format the `SaleDate` variable to a month level render.  The output structure will be slightly different than `BY`.  The `CLASS` statement causes a *tighter* output.  This example also uses `NDEC` to reduce the number of decimal places.

```
DATA sales;
input CustID $ SaleDate : MMDDYY10. Petunia SnapDragon Marigold;
datalines;
756-01 05/04/2013 120 80 110
834-01 05/12/2013 90 160 60
901-02 05/18/2013 50 100 75
834-01 06/01/2013 80 60 100
756-01 06/11/2013 10 160 75
901-02 06/19/2013 60 60 60
756-01 06/25/2013 85 110 100
;

PROC MEANS DATA=sales ndec=2;
  VAR Petunia SnapDragon Marigold;
  class SaleDate;
  format SaleDate yymon7.;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep your data step statements inside of your data step.  You cannot put them in between two steps.

Your assignment statement is after the data step and before the extra, do nothing, `RUN;` statement.  Move it before the `DATALINES;` statement.

```
data sales;
  input CustID $ @9 SaleDate :MMDDYY10. Petunia SnapDragon Marigold;
  Month = MONTH(SaleDate);
datalines;
```

For a data step that uses in-line data the data is the last thing in the step.  I would also remove that extra `RUN;` statement to avoid this type of confusion.